# How to place some important information like credentials in scenario outline example in a separate file for Specflow 3.9.22?

Tags: specflow

For specflow 2.4 and earlier there was Specflow.Plus.Excel nuge-package, but it's not available for newer versions. Is there an alternative for having scenario outline example in a separate file so that I can add that file to .gitignore?

Additional clearification after comments with questions:
What I'm trying to do is to put multiple credentials into scenario outline examples, but I don't want to store credentials in the repo while I want to store scenario outline in repo. So I wanted to put examples with multiple credentials in a separate file, add that file to gitignore but make scenario outline use that separate local file as a source of parameters (examples). In earlier versions it was available via excel file.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The title appears to ask about how to put credentials in an example outline, and the body text appears to ask about using Excel files to drive tests... and I'm not sure where the .gitignore file fits into all of this.

Comment: I was trying to do exactly what you've just described: put multiple credentials into scenario outline examples, but I don't want to store credentials in the repo while I want to store scenario outline in repo. So I wanted to put examples with multiple credentials in a separate file, add that file to gitignore but make scenario outline use that separate local file as a source of parameters (examples). In earlier versions it was available via excel file.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a scenario where you might need credentials? Are these credentials and users different per application environment?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Sure, just edited. Well, it should be possible to use either same or different credentials locally - whatever user desires.

Comment: But *why* do you need multiple credentials in your scenario outline? Are you writing tests for a login page? I can think about about 8 ways to accomplish what you are asking, but the use case you are writing the scenario outline for will determine which solution I answer with. What are you testing? A scenario that requires someone to log in, or are you testing the actual login form?

Comment: Actually it's not testing. It's automation of certain job in browser. So same actions need to be executed from different users.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. It's a little late at my end of the world tonight. I will attempt an answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: Why not an environment variable or a "secret" (which is basically an environment variable)?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, environment variable doesn't seem to be a correct place to contain credentials for one of multiple projects on a PC. It has nothing to do with a system.